Corner cases for Longest Common Substring problem?
I have been working on an exercise that gives two string s and t, find the longest common substring by outputting 3 integers: its starting position in s, its starting position in t (all 0-based), and its length. For example: cool toolbox would output 1 1 3. If there are multiple answers with same maximal length, output any of them.
Here is the original statement:
Input Format: Every line of the input contains two strings s and t consisting of lower case Latin letters.
Constraints: The total length of all s’s as well as the total length of all t’s does not exceed 10^5.
Output Format: For each pair of strings s and t, find its longest common substring and specify it by
outputting three integers: its starting position in s, its starting position in t (both 0-based), and its
length. More formally, output integers 0 ≤  < ||, 0 ≤  < ||, and  ≥ 0 such that +1 · · · +−1 =
+1 · · · +−1 and  is maximal. (If there are many such triples with maximal , output any of them.)
Time Limits: Java: 5 sec
Memory Limits: 512MB
I used the binary search to find the longest length possible and polynomial hash approach to find the substring itself. The code (including stress test) is below:
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class common_substring {
    private static int prime1 = 2000000033;
    private static int prime2 = 1000000007;
    private static int multiplier = 97;

    public class Answer {
        int i, j, len;
        Answer(int i, int j, int len) {
            this.i = i;
            this.j = j;
            this.len = len;
        }
    }

    public Answer solveNaive(String s, String t) {
        Answer ans = new Answer(0, 0, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < t.length(); j++)
                for (int len = 0; i + len <= s.length() && j + len <= t.length(); len++)
                    if (len > ans.len && s.substring(i, i + len).equals(t.substring(j, j + len)))
                        ans = new Answer(i, j, len);
        return ans;
    }

    public Answer solve(String s, String t) {
        Answer ans = new Answer(0, 0, 0);

        int minLen = Math.min(s.length(), t.length());
        int shortest = 0, longest = minLen;
        
        // Use binary search to find the length of LONGEST common substring
        while (shortest <= longest) {
            int mid = (shortest + longest) / 2; 
            // In case shortest == 0 and longest == 1, cover the case l = 1
            if (shortest == 0 && longest == 1)
                mid = 1;
            Answer tmp = getSubString(mid, s, t);
            if (tmp.len != 0) {
                shortest = mid + 1;
                ans = tmp;
            }
            else
                longest = mid - 1;
        }

        return ans;
    }

    private Answer getSubString(int l, String s, String t) {
        Answer ans = new Answer(0, 0, 0);

        // Compute the (polynomial) hashes of all substrings of length l
        // First hash
        ArrayList<Long> subHashes1_S = new ArrayList<Long>(s.length() - l + 1);
        ArrayList<Long> subHashes1_T = new ArrayList<Long>(t.length() - l + 1);
        subHashes1_S.add(0, (long) hashFunc1(s.substring(0, l)));
        subHashes1_T.add(0, (long) hashFunc1(t.substring(0, l)));
        // Multiplier for the next substring
        long y1 = (new BigInteger(Integer.toString(multiplier))
            .modPow(new BigInteger(Integer.toString(l)), new BigInteger(Integer.toString(prime1))))
            .longValue(); // (multiplier ^ k) % prime1

        for (int i = 1; i <= s.length() - l; i++) {
            subHashes1_S.add(i, ((subHashes1_S.get(i - 1) * multiplier + s.charAt(i + l - 1) - s.charAt(i - 1) * y1) % prime1 + prime1) % prime1);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= t.length() - l; i++) {
            subHashes1_T.add(i, ((subHashes1_T.get(i - 1) * multiplier + t.charAt(i + l - 1) - t.charAt(i - 1) * y1) % prime1 + prime1) % prime1);
        }

        // Second hash
        ArrayList<Long> subHashes2_S = new ArrayList<Long>(s.length() - l + 1);
        ArrayList<Long> subHashes2_T = new ArrayList<Long>(t.length() - l + 1);
        subHashes2_S.add(0, (long) hashFunc2(s.substring(0, l)));
        subHashes2_T.add(0, (long) hashFunc2(t.substring(0, l)));
        // Multiplier for the next substring
        long y2 = (new BigInteger(Integer.toString(multiplier))
            .modPow(new BigInteger(Integer.toString(l)), new BigInteger(Integer.toString(prime2))))
            .longValue(); // (multiplier ^ k) % prime2

        for (int i = 1; i <= s.length() - l; i++) {
            subHashes2_S.add(i, ((subHashes2_S.get(i - 1) * multiplier + s.charAt(i + l - 1) - s.charAt(i - 1) * y2) % prime2 + prime2) % prime2);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= t.length() - l; i++) {
            subHashes2_T.add(i, ((subHashes2_T.get(i - 1) * multiplier + t.charAt(i + l - 1) - t.charAt(i - 1) * y2) % prime2 + prime2) % prime2);
        }

        // Compare hashes of two substrings
        // Keys represent the hashes, values represent the indices
        HashMap<Long, Integer> exclusive1 = new HashMap<Long, Integer>(), exclusive2 = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < subHashes1_S.size(); i++) {
            exclusive1.put(subHashes1_S.get(i), i);
            exclusive2.put(subHashes2_S.get(i), i);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < subHashes1_T.size(); j++) {
            if (exclusive1.containsKey(subHashes1_T.get(j)) && exclusive2.containsKey(subHashes2_T.get(j)))
                ans = new Answer(exclusive1.get(subHashes1_T.get(j)), j, l);
        }
        
        return ans;
    }

    private static int hashFunc1(String s) {
        long hash = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
            hash = (hash * multiplier + s.charAt(i)) % prime1;
        return (int)hash;
    }

    private static int hashFunc2(String s) {
        long hash = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
            hash = (hash * multiplier + s.charAt(i)) % prime2;
        return (int)hash;
    }

    public void run() {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        in.lines().forEach(line -> {
            StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(line);
            String s = tok.nextToken();
            String t = tok.nextToken();
            Answer ans = solve(s, t);
            out.format("%d %d %d\n", ans.i, ans.j, ans.len);
        });

        // Stress test
        // boolean again = true;
        // while (again) {
        //     // choose a Character random from this String 
        //     String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        //     Random random = new Random();

        //     // create StringBuffer size of AlphaNumericString 
        //     StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(); 
        //     StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

        //     for (int i = 0; i < 120; i++) { 

        //         // add Character one by one in end of sb 
        //         sb1.append(alphabet.charAt(random.nextInt(26)));
        //         sb2.append(alphabet.charAt(random.nextInt(26)));
        //     }

        //     String s = sb1.toString();
        //     String t = sb2.toString();
        //     // s = "yslhjqrnyecavqucgiucgxmn";
        //     // t = "svilryrdllesupkdhkwhbdzh";

        //     Answer ans = solve(s, t);
        //     Answer nai = solveNaive(s, t);
        //     System.out.println(s + " " + t);
        //     System.out.println(String.format("Answer: %d %d %d", ans.i, ans.j, ans.len));
        //     System.out.println(String.format("Naive : %d %d %d", nai.i, nai.j, nai.len));
            
        //     again = ans.len == nai.len;
        // }
        out.close();
    }

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        new common_substring().run();
    }
}


However, it seems like there are corner cases that I haven't taken into account yet, as the grader keeps rejecting my solution by saying "Wrong Answer" on a specific case. The problem is that I have no access to the input. Stress test runs fine. Any idea what could this corner case be?

Where is the grader? Although we know what the "longest common substring problem" is, it might if we could see the description of the problem that goes along with the grader you are using. My first thought is to take a close look at the constraints.

@OldDogProgrammer I added the original statement. The grader is from the Coursera course "Data Structures". Here is the direct link to it although I doubt you can access without signing in

am I correct that posted code is using (only) hash codes to check if the substrings are equal? Is it possible that two different substrings have the same hash code? (no problem to find such strings using the hash code of the String class)

@user85421 It is possible. That is why I am using two hash functions instead of one to further reduce the collision rate. But nice catch, I'll try directly comparing the substrings
